# conditional order by to based on two columns with some limits

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck on a query..

I have a table of ads..There I have column sort_order and date_added.sort_order is set base on group type.So on my page say I want to show 12 ads by 4 groups.

I want 3 ads have order 1 at top in dec order by date_added.

Then 3 ads have order 2  in dec order by date_added.

Then 3 ads have order 3  in dec order by date_added.

Then 3 ads have order 4  in dec order by date_added.

so on front end it should look like this

```
Name    date_added sort_order
ad1      12-2-2015   1
ad2      11-2-2015   1
ad3      10-2-2015   1

ad4      13-2-2015   2
ad5      12-2-2015   2
ad6      07-2-2015   2

ad7      18-2-2015   3
ad8      10-2-2015   3
ad9      03-2-2015   3

ad10      12-2-2015   4
ad11      08-2-2015   4
ad12      03-2-2015   4
```

If `sort_order=1` have only 2 ads then `sort_order=2` can show 4 ads.
Is it achievable by single query.Please give a advise.

What I am trying is

```
Select name,sort_order,date_added form ads order by sort_order ASC,date_added DESC LIMIT 0,12
```

Its not diving results in equal parts for each group.

Answer (score 1):

This is easiest with `union all`:

```
select t.*
from ((Select name, sort_order, date_added 
       from ads
       where sort_order = 1
       order by date_added desc
       LIMIT 4
      ) union all
      (Select name, sort_order, date_added 
       from ads
       where sort_order = 2
       order by date_added desc
       LIMIT 4
      ) union all
      (Select name, sort_order, date_added 
       from ads
       where sort_order = 3
       order by date_added desc
       LIMIT 4
      ) union all
      (Select name, sort_order, date_added 
       from ads
       where sort_order = 4
       order by date_added desc
       LIMIT 4
      )
     ) t
order by sort_order, date_added desc;
```

However, this gets harder if you want 12 rows but might not have the intermediate rows.  Allocating the extra values is challenging.  Here is one approach:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             (@rn := if(@so = sort_order, @rn + 1,
                        if(@so := sort_order, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) seqnum
      from ads s cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @so := 0) vars
      order by sort_order, date_added desc
     ) s
where @rn <= 12
order by (case when @rn <= 4 then @rn else @rn + sort_order + 100 end)
limit 12;
```

Comment: Awesome..Let me try..One question say if there is no ad exist where sort_order=1 can second show 6?

Comment: @AsifAsghar . . . I think the second version does this.

Comment: I again need your help. I tried it before and it gives me unknown table s error. If I replaced t with s it gives me empty result. That time client said leave it if it is tricky. Now he is asking again to do this. Please can you help. Should I send you sql table backup?